# Python and Scrapy referencing item's attributes

Tags: python, variables, web-scraping, scrapy

On Scrapy's tutorial site they have this code for an item.

```
import scrapy

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
```

then they have this code for the spider.

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            yield item
```

My question is why can they reference item's title using the [] brackets? I thought when you reference a variable it would be item.title = whatever. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because under the hood Scrapy uses [`UserDict.DictMixin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html#UserDict.DictMixin) mixin for the [`Item`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#module-scrapy.item) class:

> `class UserDict.DictMixin`
>
> Mixin defining all dictionary methods for classes that already have a
>   minimum dictionary interface including `__getitem__()`, `__setitem__()`,
>   `__delitem__()`, and `keys()`.

Also, the quote from Scrapy's [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#module-scrapy.item):

> Item objects are simple containers used to collect the scraped data.
>   They provide a dictionary-like API with a convenient syntax for
>   declaring their available fields.

Also see [the actual implementation](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/item.py).